# How to parse the resource section of a PE executable using C/C++?

Tags: windows, reverse-engineering, implementation, portable-executable

I am trying to understand how PE files work and I'm developing a small application in C/C++ as well as Python to parse a *.exe file and get the version information only from the file.
In essence I'm trying to find the original file name, manufacturer etc from the file.
I tried reading the Microsoft documentation regarding PE and COFF file formats, but I'm unable to implement the idea in a practical manner.

From what I understood:
Every PE file starts with a MS DOS application stub, that simply prints out the application cannot be run in DOS Mode   :)
Then we have to find an offset which takes us to the magic "PE\0\0" followed by some structures.
After which we can get to the section table and from there to the resources.

But my understanding is very peripheral and I don't think I will be able to implement a very concrete application based on this info.

I would really love to get some resources where I can get a deep understanding of how this works. In particular I would really love to know, how to parse the resource tree and get information like version, icon, etc.

It would be absolutely amazing and a great blessing if anyone could help me :)
Every help will be greatly appreciated  :)

Comment: Do you want to read the header? You can find the addresses here: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Portable_Executable_32_bit_Structure_in_SVG_fixed.svg

Comment: @vll +1, Thankyou very much for your immediate response :) Can you please tell me how I can get to the resources section, please?

Comment: first you need load PE to memory, if it not already loaded. better with `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE`. then use or (more efficient) `LdrFindResource_U` + `LdrAccessResource` or `FindResource` + `LoadResource` (stupid implementation) +`SizeofResource` for `RT_VERSION, MAKEINTRESOURCE(1)` - you got pointer to `VS_VERSIONINFO` and from it you can got pointer to `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO`